# My lennox furnace has no filter

Tags: furnace, filter, lennox

I searched for 30 minutes, and I could not find the furnace filter, is it possible to install/build a filter slot? my whole family got allergy after turning on heater this winter.  Thank you!

[image]
Lennox 80mgf4-75a
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50982191/IMG_1425.JPG[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it mastic-ed over? Take the bottom panel off the furnace and look inside that duct. Is there a 1" channel for a filter in it? I really hope you *don't* find an old filter in there...

Comment: Jimmy, thanks, I do have a filter at the return-air grill, after searching on internet and you tube, I thought I should have another one in the attic. I guess that's not true ?

Comment: Thanks  Mazura, I looked, there is no moving part in that unit that looks like a filter.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I will open up that big tube and clean it myself this weekend. the house was build in 1998, air duct never got cleaned before.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Lennox too and I hate the filter situation with a fury of 1000 suns:

[image]
[image]

It's just sitting in the furnace against the return duct - previous owner left a VERY dirty one taped with aluminum tape that took me a long time to peel. I've been using masking tape. One of these days I'll find time to fabricate a filter box to sit between the return duct and the furnace.

So, I'm guessing from your pictures that you'd be in the same situation - inside the furnace, against the mastic'ed duct.

Comment: +1 for "fury of 1000 suns"! And for the pictures and description.

Comment: Is this the only place you have filter? for me, I don't see this filter even after I opened up the furnace, but I have a 1" filter in the  return-air grill that located in the ceiling of living room.

Comment: Yes, it's the only place for me. My return is a duct that opens to a hole in the subfloor. How does the filter in the return look - very dirty? Your system is probably designed to take the filter on the return side - don't be tempted to add a second filter in the furnace, that could put strain on the blower, just like a single super-fine filter with a high MPR-value might.

Comment: I am at work, but my return looks like this, it's in the ceiling. [link](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRRbEmtz2wa2NUiMflIwRESMNXlyiqd4I_cA9e-Tdh46LkUbh08)

Comment: I replaced the 1" filter about 3 month ago, so it should not be too dirty. I noticed a lot of people are coughing when weather turned cold, maybe most of them got the same allergy from heater

Comment: So your picture of the return most certainly shows a filter in place. If your concern now is that the furnace is causing allergies, I'm afraid I can't give you much information on that. If you think it's dust, you can do two things: 1st, your furnace is most definitely not air-tight and will not be pulling all of the supply air through the filter, it will be pulling a very small amount through small holes in the duct, through the gas line supply hole, etc. Make sure the bottom of the furnace and around it is free of dust & other particles; clean out the ductwork too if it's dirty.

Comment: 2nd: you can try a filter with a higher MPR/MERV rating - the ones you're using right now _may_ let the finer particles through, although that's just a guess. Now, **be careful** with getting a filter that's too fine - it will be much harder for the furnace to pull air through it, so the furnace will work harder and that may shorten its life. Usually furnaces have a rating for inflow/outflow and you don't want to mess with either of those too much. Unfortunately, I can't tell you what your furnace is rated for, you'll have to find docs online or have an HVAC pro look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Modern residential systems frequently have the filter located at the return-air grill. Look for the large grill where blower air is pulled in from the house; if the grill has small latches and hinge tabs, where it can swing open, it is probably designed to have a slim furnace filter installed behind the grill.

Comment: In that case you'd have to have a filter on **every** return, of which there could be one in every room.

Comment: @tester101, a **single** return air grill and duct (with filter) can supply most residential forced-air systems. Fact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be possible to install a filter. You would need some sheet metal and know-how, or you might get lucky and find something pre-made.  A qualified HVAC technician could make one easily.

You might also consider getting your ducts cleaned to help reduce the dust.

Comment: A duct cleaning would help in the very short term, and would be short lived.  Without a filter; or regular cleaning of the furnace, the lifetime of the furnace will be reduced.